# how to change the form design to be create right-to-left on ms access?

Tags: ms-access

I am building a forms that's based on right to left design(Arabic) but my environment is in English which is left to right based language. so once I create form it be based on left to right I want to build forms that's right to left while using English as my environment language.

Answer (score 0):

Access has an **Orientation** property for [forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.orientation) and [reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.report.orientation), which can be set to either **Right to Left** or **Left to Right** in the form/report designer, or to `1` (for RTL) or `0` (for LTR) in code.

Note that after you set the **Orientation** to **Right to Left**, even though the form/report background itself will still be left-aligned within the designer window (and AFAICT there's no way to change this), the behavior will be RTL.

Comment: how to I set the orientation

Comment: @AbdallahRizk The form and report designer has a **Properties** pane, where you can set all the properties of the selected control. If you want to set properties on the form or report, either choose `Form` or `Report` from the dropdown in the Properties pane, or click on the intersection of the horizontal and vertical rulers.